# Chinese Remainder Theorem and the RSA Cryptosystem

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

From [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/rsa-in-plain-english) and [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87718/rsa-how-eulers-theorem-is-used) I know that the RSA cryptosystem works like this:

$\bullet$ Let $N=pq$, where $p,q$ are primes, and

$\bullet$ choose $c$, an integer relatively prime to $(p-1)(q-1)$,

Then we can take $m$, the plaintext message, and decode it by computing 
$$a = m^c \pmod N.$$

To decode the message, we need $d = c^{-1} \pmod {\varphi (N)}$, i.e. $cd \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi (N)}$, where $\varphi (N) = (p-1)(q-1)$.

**My Question**

Once we have $d$, then the claim is that 
$$ m \equiv (m^c)^d \pmod N.$$
Equivalently, since $cd \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi (N)} \Leftrightarrow cd = 1 + k\varphi (N)$,  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the claim is that 
$$ m \equiv m^{1 + k\varphi (N)} \pmod N.$$
Which means that 
$$m^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1 \pmod N .$$

Now, I know that by Fermat's little theorem
$$ m^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p \quad \text{and} \quad m^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q. $$

This implies that 
$$ m^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1 \pmod p \quad \text{and} \quad m^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1 \pmod q. $$

> I don't see how to get from this that $$ m^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1 \pmod N. $$
>   I know it follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but  I don't know how to use the theorem to get there since I think that the theorem only says that there is a solution and not what the solution is.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, so if both of them divide the difference $m^{\varphi(N)}-1$ then $N$ will divide that difference, and vice versa.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I see that if both $p$ and $q$ divide the difference, then $N$ will divide the difference. (which answers my question), but I don't understand the vice versa? If $N$ divides some nonero integer, than it follows that *either* $p$ or $q$ has to divide that integer. But why would it follow that both divide that integer?

Comment: Yes, some call this a proof by CRT, but it is a much simpler, specified version.  You don't need the full force version.  It's just what @StinkingBishop said above.

Comment: @Jess No, if $N$ divides an integer, then *both* $p$ and $q$ divide that integer by transitivity of "divides" relation (since both $p$ and $q$ already divide $N=pq$),

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, that's obvious. Thanks!