# How are prime numbers used to facilitate modern encryption?

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are very large prime numbers important in cryptography?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/why-are-very-large-prime-numbers-important-in-cryptography)

I'm interested in how the algorithms for creating key pairs to be used in dual key encryption work.  I have looked them up and they are a little too much for me to parse at my level but I could really use a conceptual explanation of how prime numbers fit into the picture (they seem to the the key to it all).

Another way of saying this is I know what dual key encryption is and I know what prime  numbers are.  I would like to understand what properties of the one connects it to the other.

A related curiosity is this: if prime numbers are spread out and hard to find, how is there a seemingly unlimited number of key pairs and how can programs generate them so quickly?

Comment: Have you seen [this question and answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7377/742)?

Comment: For your "curiosity", the primes of practical length (say 256 to 1024 bits) are indeed sparse, but not so sparse that you can't generate one by picking a random bit pattern an testing whether it is prime. (Rinse and repeat.) Luckily for us, we have efficient algorithms to test primality (with a few provisos that we won't deal with in a comment).