# Prime and co-prime numbers importance in Cryptography

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

I am currently writing a math paper for school regarding RSA encryption my focus lies on the importance of prime and co-prime numbers within the algorithm.

I understand that this is a "trap-door" algorithm which means that it is difficult to find the prime factors of a large number *n* as non-quantum computers without the correct algorithm are unable to perform this within a reasonable amount of time. However, if you have the prime factors of the number *n* it is simple to apply the algorithm.

Currently, I have looked at another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/why-are-very-large-prime-numbers-important-in-cryptography) which gave me a deeper insight into the topic but I feel although there is crucial information missing.

**Hence, my question is** whether there is something I could add to increase the complexity of my answer with regards to why prime and co-prime numbers are of such importance in encryption (more specifically RSA).

Comment: Maybe, you can mention that the safety of this method has not been proven, not even assuming the enemy cannot factor the public number.

Comment: One needs to mention that the random number generator must be good since one can [GCD them all](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298) to factor some! This happened in practice. Also, note that some bad random number generators can lead to Fermat factoring method if they are close to each other.

Comment: Considering also the last comment, the conclusion is that this method is after all not good and allows too many attacks to be considered to be safe. Unfortunately , it is nevertheless widely used.